# Как при нажатии на один блок пересчитать расстояние?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Данный скрипт при загрузке страницы определяет расстояние от верхней части экрана до верхней точки блока `#sticky-sidebar`, когда этому же блоку `#sticky-sidebar` необходимо принять фиксированную позицию `position:fixed`, и обратно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать, чтобы скрипт пересчитывал это расстояние и при нажатии на `.menu_sidebar > ul.cats > li.cat > a`? Благодарю за помощь!

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.stickyBox = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            notStickyBreakpoint: 1024,
            spaceTop: 0,
            stopper: true,
            stopperSpace: 0
        };
        var config = $.extend(defaults, options);
        if ($(window).innerWidth() <= config.notStickyBreakpoint) {
            return this;
        }
        var stopper;
        if (config.stopper !== false) {
            stopper = $(config.stopper).first();
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            var box = $(this);
            box.initialStyle = box.attr('style');
            box.parentElement = box.parent();
            box.alreadyStopped = false;
            setBoxProperties(box);
            $(window).on('resize', function() {
                setBoxProperties(box);
                setBoxPosition(box);
            });
            setBoxPosition(box);
            $(window).on('scroll', function() {
                setBoxPosition(box);
            });
        });
        function setBoxProperties(box) {
            resetBox(box);
            var offsetTop = box.offset().top;
            var offsetLeft = box.offset().left;
            var boxSizing = box.css('box-sizing');
            var width;
            if (boxSizing == 'border-box') {
                width = box.outerWidth();
            } else {
                width = box.width();
            }
            box.intialOffsetTop = offsetTop;
            box.intialOffsetLeft = offsetLeft;
            box.initialWidth = width;
        }
        function setBoxPosition(box) {
            if (!box.alreadyStopped && (($(window).scrollTop() >= box.intialOffsetTop - config.spaceTop) || (box.stopPosition !== undefined && $(window).scrollTop() >= box.stopPosition))) {
                box.parentElement.css({
                    position: 'relative'
                });
                var position = 'fixed';
                var top = config.spaceTop;
                if (box.stopPosition !== undefined && $(window).scrollTop() >= box.stopPosition) {
                    position = 'absolute';
                    top = box.stopPosition + config.spaceTop - box.parentElement.offset().top;
                }
                box.css({
                    position: position,
                    top: top,
                    marginTop: 0,
                    width: box.initialWidth
                });
            } else {
                resetBox(box);
            }
        }
        function resetBox(box) {
            if (box.initialStyle !== undefined) {
                box.attr('style', box.initialStyle);
            } else {
                box.removeAttr('style');
            }

            if (config.stopper !== false && stopper.length > 0) {
                var stopperTop = stopper.offset().top;
                if (stopperTop > box.offset().top + box.outerHeight() + config.stopperSpace) {
                    box.alreadyStopped = false;
                    box.stopPosition = stopperTop - (config.spaceTop + box.outerHeight() + config.stopperSpace);
                } else {
                    box.alreadyStopped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sticky-sidebar').stickyBox({
        stopperSpace: 0,
        stopper: '.footer'
    });
});
```

Плагин: Stickybox - https://github.com/joergmoldenhauer/jquery-stickybox
Код раскрытия/скрытия меню:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu_sidebar > ul.cats > li.cat > a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('toggle').parent().toggleClass('toggle');
    $(this).parent().children('.menu_sidebar > ul.cats > li.cat > ul.catlist').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('.menu_sidebar-arrow').toggleClass('menu_sidebar-arrow-active');
});
});
```

Comment: Добавьте html и css для наглядности

Comment: При раскрытии меню вам нужно обновлять значение позиции, при которой блок принимает `position:fixed`

Comment: Добавьте код обработчика раскрытия/скрытия меню. И уточните - откуда был взят плагин stickyBox?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Теперь можно забыть про дублирующий обработчик. По вашим вопросам: 1) Да, будет делать перерасчет. Главное - прописывать `.trigger('update');` по завершению любой операции, которая будет влиять на положение липкого блока; 2) Теперь я использовать ваш код - все работает отлично. Проблема была в том, что в настройках указано `notStickyBreakpoint: 1024`, а окно редактирования кода тут меньше, поэтому скрипт и не срабатывал

Comment: Ну как, заработало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для обновления свойст и положения `#sticky-sidebar`'а нужно дописать публичный метод, например `update`, и применять его при открытии/скрытии меню (начинается со строки `return box.bind('update', function() {`):

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery.fn.stickyBox = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
      notStickyBreakpoint: 1024,
      spaceTop: 0,
      stopper: true,
      stopperSpace: 0
    };
    var config = $.extend(defaults, options);
    if ($(window).innerWidth() <= config.notStickyBreakpoint) {
      return this;
    }
    var stopper;
    if (config.stopper !== false) {
      stopper = $(config.stopper).first();
    }
    return this.each(function() {
      var box = $(this);
      box.initialStyle = box.attr('style');
      box.parentElement = box.parent();
      box.alreadyStopped = false;
      setBoxProperties(box);
      $(window).on('resize', function() {
        setBoxProperties(box);
        setBoxPosition(box);
      });
      setBoxPosition(box);
      $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        setBoxPosition(box);
      });
      return box.bind('update', function() {
        setBoxProperties(box);
        setBoxPosition(box);
      });
    });

    function setBoxProperties(box) {
      resetBox(box);
      var offsetTop = box.offset().top;
      var offsetLeft = box.offset().left;
      var boxSizing = box.css('box-sizing');
      var width;
      if (boxSizing == 'border-box') {
        width = box.outerWidth();
      } else {
        width = box.width();
      }
      box.intialOffsetTop = offsetTop;
      box.intialOffsetLeft = offsetLeft;
      box.initialWidth = width;
    }

    function setBoxPosition(box) {
      if (!box.alreadyStopped && (($(window).scrollTop() >= box.intialOffsetTop - config.spaceTop) || (box.stopPosition !== undefined && $(window).scrollTop() >= box.stopPosition))) {
        box.parentElement.css({
          position: 'relative'
        });
        var position = 'fixed';
        var top = config.spaceTop;
        if (box.stopPosition !== undefined && $(window).scrollTop() >= box.stopPosition) {
          position = 'absolute';
          top = box.stopPosition + config.spaceTop - box.parentElement.offset().top;
        }
        box.css({
          position: position,
          top: top,
          marginTop: 0,
          width: box.initialWidth
        });
      } else {
        resetBox(box);
      }
    }

    function resetBox(box) {
      if (box.initialStyle !== undefined) {
        box.attr('style', box.initialStyle);
      } else {
        box.removeAttr('style');
      }

      if (config.stopper !== false && stopper.length > 0) {
        var stopperTop = stopper.offset().top;
        if (stopperTop > box.offset().top + box.outerHeight() + config.stopperSpace) {
          box.alreadyStopped = false;
          box.stopPosition = stopperTop - (config.spaceTop + box.outerHeight() + config.stopperSpace);
        } else {
          box.alreadyStopped = true;
        }
      }
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

$('#sticky-sidebar').stickyBox({
  stopperSpace: 200,
  stopper: '.footer'
});

$('.left').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.block').slideToggle(function() {
    $('#sticky-sidebar').trigger('update');
  });

});
```

```css
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-color: #ECF0F1
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #666;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.left {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #666;
}

#sticky-sidebar {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 3px solid #C0392B;
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 250px;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  height: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  height: 200px;
}

.container {
  padding: 0;
}

.left,
.main {
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.main {
  width: 75%;
  border-left: 1px solid #666;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 940px;
  }
  .header {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 600px;
  }
}


/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 1140px;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="sticky-sidebar" id="sticky-sidebar">
        Sticky Element
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <h1>jQuery Stickybox Plugin Demo</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
        dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>
      <p>Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper
        libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci
        eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero.</p>
      <p>Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
        posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget,
        posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus
        non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan
        cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit.</p>
      <p>Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna
        dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum
        primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. In dui magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Aenean viverra rhoncus
        pede. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Vivamus quis mi. Phasellus a est. Phasellus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur at lacus
        ac velit ornare lobortis. Curabitur a felis in nunc fringilla tristique.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
        dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>
      <p>Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper
        libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci
        eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero.</p>
      <p>Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
        posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget,
        posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus
        non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan
        cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit.</p>
      <p>Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna
        dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum
        primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. In dui magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Aenean viverra rhoncus
        pede. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Vivamus quis mi. Phasellus a est. Phasellus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur at lacus
        ac velit ornare lobortis. Curabitur a felis in nunc fringilla tristique.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
        dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>
      <p>Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper
        libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci
        eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero.</p>
      <p>Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
        posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget,
        posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus
        non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan
        cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit.</p>
      <p>Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna
        dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum
        primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. In dui magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Aenean viverra rhoncus
        pede. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Vivamus quis mi. Phasellus a est. Phasellus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur at lacus
        ac velit ornare lobortis. Curabitur a felis in nunc fringilla tristique.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer" id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

В вашем случае `$('#sticky-sidebar').trigger('update');` нужно поместить в `callback`-функцию в `.slideToggle()`, чтобы пересчитывать положение блока только после открытия/скрытия меню:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu_sidebar > ul.cats > li.cat > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('toggle').parent().toggleClass('toggle');
    $(this).parent().children('.menu_sidebar > ul.cats > li.cat > ul.catlist').slideToggle(function() {$('#sticky-sidebar').trigger('update');});
    $(this).find('.menu_sidebar-arrow').toggleClass('menu_sidebar-arrow-active');
  });
});
```

Comment: @LADYX нет, тут я ошибся. Триггер нужно вешать не на `#sticky-box`, а на `#sticky-sidebar`

Comment: @LADYX и вам спасибо

Comment: @LADYX Здравствуйте! После подгрузки нового контента пересчитывайте положение блока все тем же методом - `$('#sticky-sidebar').trigger('update');`

Comment: @LADYX прописывать этот метод нужно в callback-функции подгрузки новых пользователей. Ищите ее в документации

Comment: @LADYX если все работает так, как вам необходимо - значит, все правильно сделали